# Spring Data Projections. Recursive problems

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have a problem with recursive projections.

What is the best way to use projections in spring data rest?

I have next entities: **Profile**, **Params** and **Chapters**.

The relations between them are the next:

-> Profile **ManyToMany** with Params.

-> Params **ManyToOne** with Chapters

I've defined my personal projections and included it in my repositories with the excerpt propertie but when I request them, the projection only have effect in the first level and in my case, when I list Profiles, I see the projection that I applied for the profile entity but not see the projection that I defined for the param entity in the second level.

Projections are here:

```
@Projection(name = "profileProjection", types = Profile.class)
public interface ProfileProjection {

    int getId();

    List<Param> getParams();

}

@Projection(name = "paramProjection", types = Param.class)
public interface ParamProjection {

    int getId();

    Chapter getChapter();

    List<Profile> getProfiles();

}
```

Also, I see the profile associate to my Params recurively when I only want to see the first level. What is the best way to stop the recursivity? I've tried to use the **projection param** in the url like this without good results.

**....../parametros?projection=parametroProjection**

Is it posible to apply two projections in a url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are asking. If you want to combine projections you can do something like:

```
@Projection(name = "profileProjection", types = Profile.class)
public interface ProfileProjection {
    int getId();

    // note type of list is ParamProjection 
    List<ParamProjection> getParams(); 
}

@Projection(name = "paramProjection", types = Param.class)
public interface ParamProjection {

    int getId();
    Chapter getChapter();
}
```

....../parametros?projection=profileProjection

Comment: Thank you! This is the solucition, I was using the same projection in all my other projection and the correct use is to create particular projections to every other projectios.